# Programatically remove docker images associated with docker build from Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am building a docker image as part of an automated build, and I want to remove the image I created and any subsequent images related to the built image.

I can remove the built image easily by specifying the name and tag (because I  can get this data via variables). But how do I remove any additional images that are pulled in by the Dockerfile? (Specifically using the `FROM` keyword, as there can be multiple `FROM` invocations in a single Dockerfile).

For example, I have an image that pulls in `python:2.7.16-alpine` in its Dockerfile. If I start with no images on the system, running `docker build -f path/to/Dockerfile` leaves me with two images: `generated-docker-image:tag` and `python:2.7.16-alpine`.

**Assuming the process runs on a system that may have other docker images on it that I do not want to remove, how do I programmatically remove my image and its associated images only?**

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `docker history` (Show the history of an image) to find all images related to the final one. I want to inform you that this solution doesn't work for multi-stage builds, because the final image has only references to images which were base layers for it.

Let me show you some example:

**1.** We create a simple `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN touch newfile
```

**2.** We build a docker image from it:

```
$ docker build -t new-image .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/2 : FROM ubuntu:latest
latest: Pulling from library/ubuntu
898c46f3b1a1: Pull complete
63366dfa0a50: Pull complete
041d4cd74a92: Pull complete
6e1bee0f8701: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:017eef0b616011647b269b5c65826e2e2ebddbe5d1f8c1e56b3599fb14fabec8
Status: Downloaded newer image for ubuntu:latest
 ---> 94e814e2efa8
Step 2/2 : RUN touch newfile
 ---> Running in ac93702f363b
Removing intermediate container ac93702f363b
 ---> 4d52ac122761
Successfully built 4d52ac122761
Successfully tagged new-image:latest
```

**3.** And now we can clean all images which were used to build the final one:

```
$ docker history new-image:latest | awk '!/IMAGE|<missing>/ {print $1}' | xargs -I {} docker rmi {}
Untagged: new-image:latest
Deleted: sha256:4d52ac122761ec1ba9f3d77606c49f98cf8c7d728d60834a87f25cede39a2027
Deleted: sha256:7f62b9533dbd6514fe0cb7f4ddc3086ad5ae45fe1c13f5eeea1cc38f575e92bd
Untagged: ubuntu:latest
Untagged: ubuntu@sha256:017eef0b616011647b269b5c65826e2e2ebddbe5d1f8c1e56b3599fb14fabec8
Deleted: sha256:94e814e2efa8845d95b2112d54497fbad173e45121ce9255b93401392f538499
Deleted: sha256:e783d8ee44ce099d51cbe699f699a04e43c9af445d85d8576f0172ba92e4e16c
Deleted: sha256:cc7fae10c2d465c5e4b95167987eaa53ae01a13df6894493efc5b28b95c1bba2
Deleted: sha256:99fc3504db138523ca958c0c1887dd5e8b59f8104fbd6fd4eed485c3e25d2446
Deleted: sha256:762d8e1a60542b83df67c13ec0d75517e5104dee84d8aa7fe5401113f89854d9
```